# Interpreting Precision-Recall Curves that Cross Each Other

Tags: precision-recall

[image]

Since the two Precision-Recall curves are crossing, I cannot decide which one is better. 
How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best model depends on what you need it for. Is your number one priority high recall or high precision? In the former case, blue seems best (*) and in the latter case the green one is better.

(*) that blue PR curve looks suspicious because you have a very long line segment there (from recall ~0.3 to 0.95). Are you sure that curve is correct?

Comment: What are the situations that the straight line occurs? Is it impossible? I'm not familiar with this topic of PR.

Comment: One situation might be that you have a data point around Precision 0.45 and Recall 0.35, and then another data point around Precision 0.0, Recall 1.0, for some reason, and your plotting program is simply drawing a straight line between them. (Or there are no Recall percentages greater than 0.35.) The other is that there is a constant tradeoff between Precision and Recall over more than half of the Recall values, which seems unusual.